# Move iTunes library from Windows XP computer to Windows 7 computer

Tags: itunes, macos, windows

On the old laptop, I just changed the library location from the default `C:` to `D:`
I also did a consolidate and now I have the entire music, movies, iTunes folders, etc. in my `D:` drive, and want to move it the new laptop.

I know I need to open iTunes by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but my problem is, that I cannot find the **.itl** file on my old laptop (at the new location of `D:`). I need this to select it on the new laptop. Where do I find my **.itl** file ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you are asking is how to search for files on Windows XP. You need to use Window's Search function to look for any files ending in .itl on your D drive. You should post this question on a Windows help forum, not on an Apple help forum.

Comment: Pls read my question clearly...It is not a Windows question...It is the APPLE ITUNES question..

Comment: Someone pls provide me a better answer...the above comments are not at all clear...

Answer (score 2):

iLounge has a great piece of instructions on how to move the iTunes library from one place to the next: http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/moving-your-itunes-library-to-a-new-hard-drive/

The ITL file in your case, probably remains on your C:\ drive.

Answer (score 1):

Read Apple's technical support documentation article:
[iTunes: How to move your music to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527)

Answer (score 0):

Read Microsoft's technical support documentation article: [How to search for files and folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308895)

Comment: Would a single answer suffice?